# getting MVC 2 form values in controller action using jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on asp.net MVC 2 application. I have a form like this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateRecordingDetails", "Recording", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmRecordingEdit" }))
   {%>
<%= Html.Hidden("AccountIDsEdit",  ViewData["AccountIDsEdit"]) %>
<%= Html.Hidden("SelId",  ViewData["SelId"]) %>
<%= Html.Hidden("EditMode", ViewData["EditMode"]) %>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 32%;">
                        <%=Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id) %>
                        <b>Person Name</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonName, new { @class = "textarea wide" , disabled ="disabled"})%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 32%;">
                        <b>Email</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "textarea wide" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 32%;">
                        <b>Notes</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, new { @class = "textarea widetextarea" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 32%;">
                        <b>Display Notes on Playback</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.DropDownList("isNotesVisible", ViewData["displayNotes"] as SelectList, new {@class = "normal" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 32%;">
                        <b>Call ID Number</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CallIDNumber, new { @class = "textarea normal", disabled = "disabled" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 32%;">
                        <b>Dblink Unique URL</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="DBLinkUniqueURL" class="small">
                            <%= Model.DBLinkUniqueURL %>
                        </span>
                        <input id="btnCopy" type="button" value="Copy to Clipboard" onclick="copyToClipboard('DBLinkUniqueURL')" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Call Password</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CallPassword, new { @class = "textarea wide", disabled = "disabled" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Number Called</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumberCalledFrom, new { @class = "textarea wide", disabled = "disabled" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Called From</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumberCalledTo, new { @class = "textarea wide", disabled = "disabled" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Call Duration</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CallDuration, new { @class = "textarea normal", disabled = "disabled" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Call Rate</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CallRate, new { @class = "textarea normal", disabled = "disabled" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Call Cost</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CallCost, new { @class = "textarea tiny", disabled = "disabled" })%>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CallCost, new { @class = "textarea normal", disabled = "disabled" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>User ID/ Email</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoginId, new { @class = "textarea wide", disabled = "disabled" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Date/Time Added</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreationDate, new { @class = "textarea wide", disabled = "disabled" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Call Status</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CallStatus, new { @class = "textarea normal", disabled = "disabled" })%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Archived</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.isArchived, new { disabled = "disabled"})%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<%            
   } 
%>
```

I have a button outside this form, which posts the form with jquery ajax like this:

```
function editAccountDetails() {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/recording/UpdateRecordingDetails",
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('frmRecordingEdit').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });   
}
```

In controller action method, I am not getting all these fields. I get only the ones which are in viewdata or which are not disabled and checkbox value. My action method is:

```
 [Authorize]
        public ActionResult UpdateRecordingDetails(FormCollection form, CallRecordingModel objCampaignMode)
        {
            return Content("testing");
        }
```

neither formcollection note the model has all the fields values which are in the form.

```
[Edit]


form has values for 

AccountIDsEdit
SelId
EditMode
Id
Email
Notes
isNotesVisible
isArchived


model has values in three fields
email, Id, notes

<td>
            <table align="center">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td style="width: 32%;">
                        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="Id" id="Id">
                        <b>Person Name</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="Asif" readonly="readonly" name="PersonName" id="PersonName" disabled="disabled" class="textarea wide">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 32%;">
                        <b>Email</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="asif@cc.com" name="Email" id="Email" class="textarea wide">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 32%;">
                        <b>Notes</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea rows="2" name="Notes" id="Notes" cols="20" class="textarea widetextarea">asif notes</textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 32%;">
                        <b>Display Notes on Playback</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="isNotesVisible" id="isNotesVisible" class="normal"><option selected="selected">Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 32%;">
                        <b>Call ID Number</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="callIDNum002" name="CallIDNumber" id="CallIDNumber" disabled="disabled" class="textarea normal">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 32%;">
                        <b>Dblink Unique URL</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="small" id="DBLinkUniqueURL">
                            http://temp.com/callIDNum002
                        </span>
                        <input type="button" onclick="copyToClipboard('DBLinkUniqueURL')" value="Copy to Clipboard" id="btnCopy">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Call Password</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="temppass" name="CallPassword" id="CallPassword" disabled="disabled" class="textarea wide">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Number Called</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="03344037289" name="NumberCalledFrom" id="NumberCalledFrom" disabled="disabled" class="textarea wide">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Called From</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="0442510406" name="NumberCalledTo" id="NumberCalledTo" disabled="disabled" class="textarea wide">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Call Duration</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="00:01:30" name="CallDuration" id="CallDuration" disabled="disabled" class="textarea normal">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Call Rate</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="4" name="CallRate" id="CallRate" disabled="disabled" class="textarea normal">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Call Cost</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="3" name="CallCost" id="CallCost" disabled="disabled" class="textarea tiny">
                        <input type="text" value="3" name="CallCost" id="CallCost" disabled="disabled" class="textarea normal">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>User ID/ Email</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="asif_hameed_371@hotmail.com" name="LoginId" id="LoginId" disabled="disabled" class="textarea wide">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Date/Time Added</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="12/19/2012 12:00:00 AM" name="CreationDate" id="CreationDate" disabled="disabled" class="textarea wide">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Call Status</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="Completed" name="CallStatus" id="CallStatus" disabled="disabled" class="textarea normal">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Archived</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="isArchived" id="isArchived" disabled="disabled"><input type="hidden" value="false" name="isArchived">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
```

[Edit2]

```
Request URL:http://localhost:62843/recording/UpdateRecordingDetails
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:SiteBrowsedCookie=1;edited value&FirstVisit=9/14/2012 5:42:08 PM; Nop.customer=61f1bf57-034a-4427-a08c-e9442061f224; glimpseState=null; glimpseClientName=null; glimpseOptions=null; ASP.NET_SessionId=lephqzclxx35mjqier5to5l4; .CRM=85A97958C0415B3C8106A7EE2B473EE00C1F53C5E428C399AC951D7AFEA5A325C8BC54225AC959917CF1754734CF8DC6BD13DAAA7DA1EE64D4A177BB3FA3529992A1E596AF6D1D4391242C412EB809F8125EC03DBC1C5A36FDAE3BAB915E2233C30E0876EFE62B3D8CAE1CCAD020DA6791EA17FD3B085C1A913C8DBF822408FD0E2AA3B19F67AFE34C9176A3783F0935D61B847D51958ABB72AB2E9491864F956A90729E; returnUrl=returnUrl=http://localhost:62843/Account/Login
Host:localhost:62843
Origin:http://localhost:62843
Referer:http://localhost:62843/Recording/Detail
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private, s-maxage=0
Connection:Close
Content-Length:8
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 21 Dec 2012 07:16:02 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:3.0
```

Please suggest solution to it.

Comment: Could you EXACTLY point out which field valus (names) you're receiving?

Comment: And also maybe post the generated HTML of the form, just to help debugging.

Comment: @max, please see updated question with html and values

Comment: @DotnetSparrow what you'r serialized data looks like?

Comment: serialize data has only values for 8 keys. see updated question for the fields i get in form and model fields

Comment: this is what you got in server side.check it in client side with developer tool.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili before or after I click save ?

Comment: absolutely after click.did you worked with Developer Tool?

Comment: not much. but i see something under network tab and selecting updaterecordingdetails. see updated question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21500/discussion-between-behnam-esmaili-and-dotnetsparrow)

Answer (score 1):

```
data: $('frmRecordingEdit').serialize(),
```

should be:

```
data: $('#frmRecordingEdit').serialize(),
```

because that's how [`id selectors`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) work in jQuery.

Also you haven't shown how/where you are calling the `editAccountDetails` function that is sending the AJAX request but if this is inside an `onsubmit` handler of the form or an `onclick` handler of a submit button of this form or an `onclick` handler of some anchor you should make sure that you return false from this handler to ensure that you are cancelling the default action and giving chance of the AJAX call to execute. If you do not cancel the default action the browser will simply redirect away from the page leaving no chance of any AJAX calls to execute.